# move constructor called on return instead of copy

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Today I found that this code doesn't work as I expect it to work.
According to my knowledg for L-values copy constructor should be called while for R-values it should choose move constructor. Otherwise what's the purpose of `std::move` which actually does nothing but casts to R-value. I was expecting that `return obj` will call copy constructor, but it calls move.
I understand that copy is useless here, but that's about rules. What if my copy constructor has a side effect and that's my case (I know that it shouldn't, but technically it can - for example here: std::cout call). 
Is there anything in standard that allows such behavior? Also how can I force a copy?

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    X() = default;

    X(const X& r): i(r.i)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    X(const X&& r): i(r.i)
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    int i = 0;
};

X foo()
{
    X obj;
    obj.i = 10;
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    X x = foo();
}
```

> move ctor
>
> move ctor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes) (emphasis mine):

> If [the returned expression] is an lvalue expression and the conditions for copy elision are met, or would be met, except that [the returned expression] names a function parameter, then overload resolution to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value is performed twice: first **as if [the returned expression] were an rvalue expression (thus it may select the move constructor or a copy constructor taking reference to const)**, and if no suitable conversion is available, overload resolution is performed the second time, with lvalue [returned expression] (so it may select the copy constructor taking a reference to non-const).
>   The above rule applies even if the function return type is different from the type of [the returned expression] (copy elision requires same type)

Long story short, `return` implicitly tries to move what you return when it makes sense. It will only copy as a last resort (no move constructor available, for example).

Comment: It's weird actually, it may silently copy if you explicitly requested move and may move if you didn't :)

Comment: @incognito indeed. That's why you should design your classes carefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer, but hope we all can benefit from an up-to-date view-point. First, we do you declare the parameter your move constructor with a const r-value ref? As far as I know, it should be non-const r-value ref because usually you want to modify the passed-in argument, am I missing something here?

Second: when I tried it in VS2022 (with C++17 compiler option), there was no output at all (both in Debug and Release modes), it looks like it is just calling the default constructor by performing Return Value Optimization (ROV).

Third: When I returned std::move(obj) the move constructor was called. Then when I tried to return const_cast<const X&>(obj), it called the copy-constructor. In both cases, default constructor was called first.