# Copy constructor and returning by value

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm learning about return value optimization and copy elision in C++ and wrote a test vector class to experiment with it in which I allocate memory for an integer array in the constructor:

```
    //Constructor:
    Vector::Vector(int s): elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {std::cout << "Constructor called"<<std::endl;}
      
    //Destructor:
    Vector::~Vector(){
        delete[] elem;
        std::cout << "Destructor is called" << std::endl;
    }
    
    double& Vector::operator[](int i){ return elem[i];}
    
    //Move constructor:
    Vector::Vector(Vector&& v): elem{v.elem}, sz{v.sz} 
    {
    std::cout << "Move constructor is called" << std::endl;
        v.elem = nullptr;
        v.sz=0;
    }
    
    //Copy constructor:
    Vector::Vector(Vector& v): elem{v.elem }, sz{v.sz} 
    {
    std::cout << "Copy constructor is called" << std::endl;
    }
```

In a main file I write a function in which I create a vector from an integer array and return it by value:

```
    Vector make(int s,int array[]){
    
    Vector v(s);
    
    for(int i =0; i<s; i++){
    v[i] = array[i];
    }
    
    return v;
    }
```

I call this in the main function as follows:

```
    int main(){
    
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    
    Vector v = make(4,a);
    
    return 0;
    }
```

When I then use the compiler option -fno-elide-constructors
the move constructor gets called when returning from function. If I get what is written in this post: [move constructor called on return instead of copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336433/move-constructor-called-on-return-instead-of-copy), the first thing the compiler tries to do is to use the move constructor and when this is not available it uses the copy constructor. So I thought that if I deleted the move constructor:

```
  Vector(Vector&&)=delete;
```

the copy constructor would be used as a last resort. If I do this however, the compiler complains that

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Vector::Vector(Vector&&)’

Vector v = make(4,a);
```

I wonder if someone can explain to me what is going on here? I know it's probably what I would want to do, but is it possible to make the copy constructor being called when returning the object from the function?

Comment: "not available" doesn't mean "deleted", it means not present. `= delete` means it's still there but trying to use it is an error. Also, once you remove the move constructor entirely, you will notice that the copy constructor doesn't copy properly (deep copy).

Comment: Fwiw, when setting up a similar example (and taking liberty to fix the non-const-proper copy-ctor), the copy-ctor is fired as expected with [g++ 11.2](https://godbolt.org/z/rPhf883s8), but fails as you report with [clang 12.01](https://godbolt.org/z/GdjoKcxas). Curious what toolchain you're using. Interestingly to me since I use a mac, apple clang-1300.0.29.30 works as g++ does.

Comment: @BoP I'm not sure I understand what you mean. (I'm relatively new to this).

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm using a makefile with CXX=g++ and CPPFLAGS =  -std=c++14, so this should be g++?

Comment: It is, but what version?  `g++ --version` should tell you. Assuming you fix your copy-ctor (and you better, as the way it is written now it isn't isn't copying; it's half-moving and a recipe for disaster), this should work. More info, btw; it also works as expected with clang 11.x and prior, but as I said, clang12.x seems dismal, even with a proper copy-ctor. Odd. Anyway, the links I provided above should provide you with what you need to test around on this if you like.

Comment: ok. that's interesting. it works with -std=c++17, but *not* -std=c++14 as you're using, with g++ 11.2

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks I see. So the issue was partly me not implementing the copy constructor correctly and due to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

copy constructor should have a const parameter :

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& v)
```

without it cannot accept a rvalue than make return

Comment: Thanks, I tried making the parameter const but I still get the same error.